# Reading A Pair Of Numbers On A Line In A File

Tags: java, java-io

I am currently working on a program that gets a user inputted file, adds the two numbers on each line, and out prints the answer into a user-made output file AND the run screen in Netbeans. I seem to only be able to do the first line, and, when printing, the second number in the line doesn't even show.

Code:­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­­

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Sums {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // Scanner for user input
        Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
        String inputFileName, outputFileName;

        // prepare the input file
        System.out.print("Input File Name: ");
        inputFileName = user.nextLine().trim();
        File input = new File(inputFileName);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(input);

        // prepare the output file
        System.out.print("Output File Name: ");
        outputFileName = user.nextLine().trim();
        // processing loop
        try (PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(outputFileName)) {
            // processing loop
            {
                while (scan.hasNext()) {
                    int Numbers = scan.nextInt();
                    double sum = 0;

                    for (int i = 0; i < Numbers; i++) {
                        sum += scan.nextDouble();
                    }

                    double total = (((sum + 1) * sum) / (2));

                    output.println("Sum From " + Numbers + "To " + Numbers + "is " + total);

                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Java != JavaScript

Comment: so do you see the result from the first line or is the program stuck after the first 'nextInt' ? `output.println` will only print to file and not screen, you need another `System.out.println` for the screen and secondly add a flush since the println might be caching the writes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and it seems to work for me.

Here is my input file content:

> 2 1 2
>
> 2 3 4

And here is the output file content:

> Sum From 2To 2is 6.0
>
> Sum From 2To 2is 28.0

I'm not quite sure if this is what you want.

---

ADD:

Code snippet:

```
while (scan.hasNext()) {
    int Numbers = scan.nextInt();
    String numberStr = "" + Numbers;
    double sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < Numbers; i++) {
        double d = scan.nextDouble();
        sum += d;
        numberStr += ", " + d;
    }

    double total = (((sum + 1) * sum) / (2));

    output.println("Sum From " + numberStr +" is " + total);
}
```

The input is:

> 2 1 2

The output is:

> Sum From 2, 1.0, 2.0 is 6.0

Comment: How about that? Is it what you want?

Comment: Yeah, but it seems to only work with one line. I need it to work for multiple lines. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a PrintWriter to print to the user made output file. Then search through the original file while scanner.hasNextInt(). Add the two next ints and print them to the file using "println()"

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    PrintWriter printwriter = new PrintWriter("newfile.txt");
    File file = new File("file.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
    int sum = 0;
    System.out.println(scanner.hasNextInt());
    while(scanner.hasNextInt()){
        printwriter.println(scanner.nextInt() + scanner.nextInt());
    }
    printwriter.close();

}
```

My input file looked like this...

```
1 2
4 2
2 4
6 4
6 7
2 3
```

And my output file looked like this...

```
3
6
6
10
13
5
```